# Issues with Results When Utilizing Microsoft Word Readability Stats

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on implementing an API approach for utilizing Microsoft Word's built in Readability Statistics. I am having issues with the ReadabilityStatistics method as it is returning incorrect results. I think it is stopping short while reading the document inputed. Documents were PDF that were scraped and converted to .docx files.

```
// Open the Word document
Document document = application.Documents.Open(filePath);

// Using ComputeStatistics

int wordCount = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticWords);

Console.WriteLine("ComputeStatistic Word Count: " + wordCount);
     
// Using Readability Stats
object index = 1;
ReadabilityStatistic readabilityStat = document.ReadabilityStatistics[ref index];
```

This approach is yielding the following results.

> ComputeStatistic Word Count: 64138
> Readability Statistic:
> Stat Name: Words
> Stat Value: 50.878998

The discrepancy between the true word count (ComputeStatistic method) and the ReadabilityStatistics output exists across documents of all lengths.